# Java Store a Connection in a HashMap

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I was hoping to build a generic HashMap to use for storing a few things, one of them being a Connection Object. This is a simplified example :

Function to initialize

```
public Map<Object, Object> genObjectInit() {

   Map<Object, Object> genObject = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

}
```

Add a connection object (as an example)

```
public Map<Object, Object> genObjectConnect(Map<Object, Object> genObject) throws Exception {

   Connection PgSQL;

   try {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      PgSQL = DriverManager.getConnection ( /* yes */ );
   } catch(Exception log) {
      throw new Exception("failed to connect");
   }

   genObject.put("PgSQL", PgSQL);

   return genObject;

}
```

Test if it's working at all

```
public void genObjectTest(Map<Object, Object> genObject) {

   genObject.put("Yes", "Yes");

   System.out.println(genObject.get("PgSQL").getClass().getName());
   genObject.get("PgSQL").close();


}
```

Adding the Connection to the HashMap seems to be working, the output from `genObject.get("PgSQL").getClass().getName()` is giving me `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection` which I assume means it is still a Connection object but calling `genObject.get("PgSQL").close();` crashes with

```
/yes/yes/yes.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
   genObject.get("PgSQL").close();
                         ^
```

I've clearly misunderstood something here. How can I use the functionality of a generically stored Connection (or equivalent but equally unique object)?

Comment: You store values as `Object` and `Object` does not have `close` method. Maybe use `Connection` type for values in your map?

Comment: You're right, changing the type to a Connection worked but does that mean HashMaps are not dynamic?

Comment: You can typecast your object into `Connection` before calling the close method

Comment: Just for knowledge, why do you want manage yourself these db connections instead of delegating `hibernate/jpa` to do so ? And if you are considering implement it yourself you better think about building a Connection pool (like `Apache Commons DBCP, HirakiCP, C3CP`) with whole setup of properties like size, max size, TTL of a connection and so on. Another point is implementing cache, at least first level cache. Good luck ;)

Comment: This is just the way I know, I'm very unfamiliar with hibernate/jpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Map<Object, Object>` gives you access to the methods declared in Object class, because when you retrieve an object from the map

```
public void genObjectTest(Map<Object, Object> genObject) {

   genObject.put("Yes", "Yes");

   System.out.println(genObject.get("PgSQL").getClass().getName());
   genObject.get("PgSQL").close();


}
```

then result of the `genObject.get("PgSQL")` is stored in an instance of the Object class.

Depending on your use case you could either try to use Java Generics with the specific type and declare your Map as `Map<Object, Connection>` like this:

```
    public void genObjectTest(Map<Object, Connection> genObject) {

        genObject.put("Yes", connectionInstance);

        System.out.println(genObject.get("PgSQL").getClass().getName());
        Connection pgSQL = genObject.get("PgSQL");
        try {
            pgSQL.close();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

which gives you many advantages, one of them is compile-time type checks, or you could eventually do type casting when retrieving an Object like:

```
public void genObjectTest(Map<Object, Object> genObject) {

    genObject.put("Yes", "Yes");

    System.out.println(genObject.get("PgSQL").getClass().getName());
    Object connectionAsObject = genObject.get("PgSQL");
    if (connectionAsObject instanceof Connection) {
        Connection pgSQL = (Connection) connectionAsObject;
        try {
            pgSQL.close();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which however is less preferred solution. With the first solution, i.e. java generics with the specific type, another advantage is that you don't have to do this type casting.